# Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument - with no character variables

Tags: r, genetics

I am running [an archived package](http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/PIGE/index.html) in a version-controlled R docker image: `rocker/rstudio:3.5.3`. I have dataset with my outcome (y), 3 covariates (cov1,..,cov3), an interaction (var_int), and roughly 19,000 single nucleotide polymorphims (snps; rsID#) for just under 2,000 participants.

When I am implementing the data.to.PIGE step, I received the error below:

```
data <- data.to.PIGE(data = dataframe, data.pathway = data.pathway, list.gene.snp = list.gene.snp, choice.pathway = c(1))
Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument
```

I am puzzled for two reasons:

**1)** I ran `sum(is.character(dataframe))` it returned:
[1] 0

and I ran  `type <- lapply(aa_pige_tlr, class)` screenshot of a section of the output is attached

**2)** I chose a random sample of SNPs (n = 992) for the first 1000 participants to use as a smaller test dataset and *everything went fine*

So I thought maybe I should just reduce the size of my dataset. So I split the master dataset into two pathway groups (n = 12k and n = 7k) but I received the same error as above for both sets.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! thanks and apologies if there is a very simple answer (I'm actually hoping there is!)

-Hannah

Comment: sorry! I realized my screenshot didn't post. The results for my lapply look liked: $rs1938027
[1] "integer"

$rs368738273
[1] "integer"

$rs184170600
[1] "integer"

$rs113981572
[1] "integer"

$rs1011152
[1] "integer"

Comment: What's the strucutre of `data.pathway`? Lookin [here](https://github.com/cran/PIGE/blob/682c43bd19a050c6b5eb055f7184e5849e60cf94/R/data.to.PIGE.R#L37) it also seems to expect those values to be numeric. Is that the case? It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Also a note about **1)**-- `is.character` returns a single logical value: `TRUE`  if that object is character or `FALSE` otherwise. I am assuming that `dataframe` is a data frame object, hence it is not a character object. So `is.character` returns `FALSE`. Logical values can be displayed as numeric with 1 representing `TRUE` and 0 representing `FALSE`. So the `sum` function is simply doing `sum(FALSE)` or `sum(0)` which returns 0.

Comment: If it's an archived package, that's because it has bugs that haven't been fixed.  Use a different package.

Comment: Consider `sum(sapply(dataframe, is.character))` if you want to count the number of character columns

Comment: Thanks @AllanCameron results of the sapply were the same: 'sum(sapply(aa_pige_tlr, is.character))
[1] 0'